# WEC linear inputs

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, design, torque, stresses

I have seen some designs being made for linear generators for WEC(wave energy) applications. A buoy driving a shaft. But what if the shaft inside was a rack and pinion? If you converted the bidirectional input coming through the pinion gear into a single direction drive output using some small pulleys and clutch bearings, you could then add some gear reductions and maintain some rotational velocity with a very small travel on a large-ish displacement. Using this mechanical conversion, how would an output compare to that of the variable output of a linear generator? Isn't the size of your displacement much more easy to change around with a mechanical conversion?

Comment: Why not use the wave motion to drive linear actuators to pump hydraulic fluid .... oh sorry that has been done and is under test.

Comment: The number of possible approaches seems pretty high to me. Are you referring to the Duck?

Comment: That approach minimised the number of connections ie friction - add to that the salty environment and then the power from the sea your idea with so many gears, teeth, bearings does not stack up too well...

Comment: Why not check out a Wells turbine.